# AngularJS Select Box

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in select box in angularjs

I'm getting my locationList using this:

```
locationFactory.getLocation().then(function (data) {
        $scope.locationList = data.data.locationList;
    });
```

and the result is this: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfLwM.png)

And this is how I add it to select box in view:

```
<select ng-options="location.strBarangay for location in locationList"
                                        ng-model="details.location" id="crOrderLoc">
                                </select>
```

My problem is, whenever I choose an option, there's always a blank option and it has a value of the first object in my json.
Example: I have a json objects [{1},{2},{3}]
And in my option it will arrange like this:

1. option value=1 (it will show empty)
2. option value=2 (it will show 1)
3. option value=3 (it will show 2)

I tried this to set the value of my model in select

```
$scope.details.location = {
        dblLocationPrice: $scope.locationList[0].dblLocationPrice,
        intLocationID: $scope.locationList[0].intLocationID,
        intLocationStatus: $scope.locationList[0].intLocationStatus,
        strBarangay: $scope.locationList[0].strBarangay,
        strCity: $scope.locationList[0].strCity
    };
```

But there's an error: 
angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at new prodSalesCtrl

But it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/3/ (edited)

But it's not working in my select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default value of the select after loading the data:

```
locationFactory.getLocation().then(function (data) {
    $scope.locationList = data.data.locationList;
    if($scope.locationList && $scope.locationList.length>0)
        $scope.details.location = $scope.locationList[0];
});
```

Comment: It's working. thank you very much.
Sorry I can't give you +rep. I'm still newbie here